# Uploading a YouTube banner through v3 Data API (From another channel)

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been trying to upload channel banners using the YouTube API through the [ChannelBanners](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelBanners) (A part of the v3 Data API).

The problem wasn't uploading as the process seems fairly simple but actually getting the image to upload.

> Call the channelBanners.insert method to upload the binary image data to YouTube. The image must have a 16:9 aspect ratio and be at least 2048x1152 pixels. We recommend uploading a 2560px by 1440px image.

Lets say I wanted to download a banner from another YouTube channel and upload it to another. The YouTube Channel API doesn't provide an image which is over 2048x1152 under their `brandingSettings`but instead provides:

```
[bannerImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w1060-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerMobileImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w640-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTabletLowImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w1138-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTabletImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w1707-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTabletHdImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w2276-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTabletExtraHdImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w2560-fcrop64=1,00005a57ffffa5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerMobileLowImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w320-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerMobileMediumHdImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w960-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerMobileHdImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w1280-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerMobileExtraHdImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w1440-fcrop64=1,32b75a57cd48a5a8-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTvImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w2120-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTvLowImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w854-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTvMediumImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w1280-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
[bannerTvHighImageUrl] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/xc4v6PgAiOeo-o3uCnh1EI9jF9oUV35vMH2eeQhhWbjWaK3ruINHzPYDJNJ3Mk_vxaBW85S-bWE=w1920-fcrop64=1,00000000ffffffff-nd-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no
```

How can I get a full resolution channel banner image from the YouTube API which is possible to then be reuploaded to another channel?

Comment: You can't get a full resolution through their API, only what you've got so far. You could resize the image prior to upload, but there would be loss of quality.

Comment: @Z.Bagley So what I'm trying to achieve isn't currently possible? I would have to get the user to upload the image or manually rescale the image myself in order to achieve this; that's unfortunate.

Comment: That's correct, sorry!

Comment: Just curious to know, why you want to download the banner image from one channel & upload that to an another channel rather than uploading the banner image of requiring size from your side?

Comment: Because I want to automatically save the current users channel and have them able to easily change it back and forth without needing to reupload it. Also helps for any ab testing